# ¿Cómo cambio el color de un elemento sin tener que recargar la página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Tengo un elemento que cambia de color cada hora. Hasta aquí todo correcto. Me gustaría que la sensación para el usuario fuese más fluida. Pongo un ejemplo:

> El elemento es de color rojo. Son las 16:59 y el usuario está leyendo algo en el sitio. Pasan a ser las 17:00, lo que en teoría, si el usuario recargara la página, vería el elemento de color azul pero lo sigue viendo rojo porque no ha recargado.

Aquí la pregunta: **¿se puede apreciar ese cambio de color sin tener que recargar la página?**

Aceptaría soluciones en Ajax y JQuery, pero quería saber si es posible no depender de frameworks para hacerlo.

Comment: Esto es un duplicado de tu pregunta [Como añadir y quitar...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410484/c%c3%b3mo-a%c3%b1adir-y-quitar-una-clase-sin-recargar-la-p%c3%a1gina-y-dependiendo-de-la-hora) te sugiero que elimines una

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La movida es mas o menos así:

- saber que hora es para el usuario
- averiguar si es de día ( 07 a 21 ) o de noche ( 21 a 07)
- cambiar la clase del elemento según si es día o noche
- calcular el próximo cambio:

  - ahora es de noche, cuándo se hace de día?
  - ahora es de día, cuándo se hace de noche?
- establecer un timer que recalcule si es de día o de noche
- volver a empezar

```js
function esDiaOesNoche(laHora) {
  return (7 <= laHora && laHora < 21) ? 'dia' : 'noche';
}

// https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
function cambiaFondoSegunTime(laHora) {
  var elCambio = esDiaOesNoche(laHora)
  console.log(`Cambiando a ${elCambio}`)
  var elBodyClass = document.querySelector('body').classList;
  elBodyClass.remove('dia', 'noche');
  elBodyClass.add(elCambio)
}

function cuantoHastaProximoCambio() {
  var hoy = new Date();
  // getMonth es un index [0-11]
  var hoyLaFecha = hoy.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (hoy.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + hoy.getDate();

  var hoyEmpiezaDia = new Date(hoyLaFecha + " 07:00:00")
  var hoyEmpiezaNoche = new Date(hoyLaFecha + " 21:00:00");
  console.log(
    hoyEmpiezaDia.toLocaleString(),
    hoyEmpiezaNoche.toLocaleString()
  )

  var maniana = new Date();
  // sumamos un día al día actual
  maniana.setDate(maniana.getDate() + 1)

  // getMonth es un index [0-11]
  var manianaLaFecha = maniana.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (maniana.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + maniana.getDate();

  var manianaEmpiezaDia = new Date(manianaLaFecha + " 07:00:00")
  var manianaEmpiezaNoche = new Date(manianaLaFecha + " 21:00:00");
  console.log(
    manianaEmpiezaDia.toLocaleString(),
    manianaEmpiezaNoche.toLocaleString()
  );
  // veamos que cambio está mas cerca
  var ahora = new Date();
  // test día casi de noche
  // ahora = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 10, 27, 23, 59, 55))

  var diffHoyEmpiezaDia = hoyEmpiezaDia - ahora;
  var diffHoyEmpiezaNoche = hoyEmpiezaNoche - ahora;
  var diffManianaEmpiezaDia = manianaEmpiezaDia - ahora;
  var diffManianaEmpiezaNoche = manianaEmpiezaNoche - ahora;

  var lasDiferencias = [
    diffHoyEmpiezaDia,
    diffHoyEmpiezaNoche,
    diffManianaEmpiezaDia,
    diffManianaEmpiezaNoche
  ];
  // debido a la flecha del tiempo ( su universo puede ser diferente )
  // si ya pasó el cambio de hoy, esperamos el primero de mañana
  // reducimos el array de diferencias al mínimo de los mayores a 0
  var masCercaHaciaAdelante = lasDiferencias.reduce(function(min, cur) {
    // retornar el mínimo de ambos sólo si es mayor a cero
    return min > 0 ? Math.min(cur, min) : cur
  }, 0)

  console.log(
    ahora.toLocaleString(),
    masCercaHaciaAdelante,
    lasDiferencias
  );
  return masCercaHaciaAdelante;
}

var elTimer;
// https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(ev) {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  document.getElementById('cambiaDia').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var elBodyClass = document.querySelector('body').classList;
    elBodyClass.remove('noche');
    elBodyClass.add('dia')
  });
  document.getElementById('cambiaNoche').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var elBodyClass = document.querySelector('body').classList;
    elBodyClass.remove('dia');
    elBodyClass.add('noche')
  });
  cambiarYcalcularProximoCambio()
});

function cambiarYcalcularProximoCambio() {
  console.log('llegó el cambio!')
  var laHoraActual = new Date().getHours();

  // test cambiando a noche
  // laHoraActual = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 10, 27, 00, 00, 55)).getHours();

  cambiaFondoSegunTime(laHoraActual);
  // calculamos el próximo cambio y le damos medio segundo mas
  var cuantoParaElTimer = cuantoHastaProximoCambio() + 500;
  console.log(`próximo cambio en ${cuantoParaElTimer/1000} segundos`)
  elTimer = setTimeout(cambiarYcalcularProximoCambio, cuantoParaElTimer)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fe0;
  color: red;
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Transiciones_de_CSS */
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear, color 700ms linear;
}

.dia {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.noche {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hola!</h1>
  <button id=cambiaDia>cambiar a día</button>
  <button id=cambiaNoche>cambiar a noche</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Fantástico, me has proporcionado justo lo que necesitaba. ¡Grande! ¿Por que hay que darle medio segundo al calcular el próximo cambio?

Comment: Se agrega medio segundo para estar seguro de que ya es de noche/día cuando se testea nuevamente la fecha/hora. El transition dispar ( 1 sec color fondo, 0.7 sec color texto) esconde el "retraso". Si tenes otro proceso haciendo polling a intervalos regulares podes recalcular y reescribir el `elTimer` con un timeout mas ajustado, siempre teniendo en cuenta no atorar al cliente ( browser/ventana/pestaña ) con cálculos innecesarios por que puede degradar la experiencia del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fecha = new Date();
var alarma = new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate(), 17, 0, 0, 0) - fecha;

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("element").style.color = "#0000FF";
}, alarma);

</script>
```